# Run-time error 13: Type mismatch on case sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue running some relatively basic "Case" code.  I keep getting a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" when the correct case is selected and the action is being executed.  In this case I have my score value as cell A6, which is stored as text.  The data is coming through via another reporting tool we use so I'm not able to modify the format of the cell value.  It will have to stay as text.  The current value is "May" so the code is running through the different cases and selecting the case "May" correctly, but will not execute the action for that case.  Any ideas on how to correct this run-time error?  I've tried all sorts of different data types for the declaration, but nothing seems to be working.  Thanks!

```
Dim score As Variant
score = Range("KPI!A6").Value
Select Case score
Case "January"
    Columns("D:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case score = "February"
    Columns("C:C,E:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "March"
    Columns("C:D,F:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "April"
    Columns("C:E,G:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "May"
    Columns("C:F,H:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "June"
    Columns("C:G,I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "July"
    Columns("C:H,J:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "August"
    Columns("C:I,K:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "September"
    Columns("C:J,L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "October"
    Columns("C:K,M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "November"
    Columns("C:L,N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Case "December"
    Columns("C:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Select
```

Comment: You can't do columns, that way, disconnected, you can however change all the `Columns` To `Range` and it will work.  BTW, did you try my code from the last question?  It should work with the text.

Comment: Does `score = Range("KPI!A6").Value` really work?

Comment: @CallumDA unfortunately it does.

Comment: @ScottCraner wow... seems like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The Range instead of columns worked out.  I didn't try it initially because I thought that it wouldn't work with text, so I just fixed what I had.  Just curious, what problems might I run into if I keep the score = Range("KPI!A6").Value ?